# "USB HDD" option replaced by "ubuntu" in BIOS, now cannot use USB boot media

Tags: boot, usb, bios

So, being foolish old me, I tried to use os-uninstaller to remove my Windows installation and make way for Arch Linux.

Unfortunately, now nothing on this computer boots, and I cannot even boot from a USB! The "USB HDD" option has completely disappeared from the BIOS and has been replaced by "ubuntu".

I can't seem to boot from anything, and was looking for a way to restore the ability to boot from USB again.

*Update - There was a recovery utility that has let me boot into Windows, but that still hasn't solved the problem of being unable to boot from USB.

If it helps, the computer is a Samsung NP540U3C and the BIOS is Phoenix Securecore Tiano Setup.

Also, why would ubuntu remove the ability to boot from USB in the first place? Very perplexed over here.

Comment: you might want to try logging on to http://unix.stackexchange.com/ using your existing stackexchange profile to ask your question over there instead.

Comment: Done. Just figured I should post here given that Ubuntu seems to be the culprit.

As a bit of an update, I apparently found a Windows recovery option in the firmware (seems to be working so far, but we'll see if it pans out).

Comment: I see this is ubuntu related, I was thinking more people may know about samsung specific issues over there.

Comment: As an update, it boots a Windows factory image now, but the ability to boot from USB is still totally and completely gone.

Comment: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=145874

Answer (score 0):

Partial fix/workaround:

- Restored Samsung factory settings, resulted in Windows factory install
- [Manually install rEFInd via Windows](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html#windows)
- Boot Arch Linux USB from rEFInd